# Using just if and elseif in a php syntax

Tags: php

This might be a noob question. I just wanna ask if it's correct to use the following codes inside a switch statement:

```
case 'OPTION1':
  if ($_SESSION['session2'] == 'cart') {  
    $code = '1567';
  }
  else if($_SESSION['session2'] == 'online') {  
    $code= 'A90f';
  } 
break;
```

Or do I always have to add an else at the end of every if elseif statements? Thank you!

Comment: No you don't have to have another else if you don't need it. In PHP the else and if are one word: elseif

Comment: No, there's no need to put an else at the end. However, you have to write code that works. For instance, given your very short example, I expect it to work even if `$code` is left undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to add an `else` and as many `else if`s as makes sense in the code, so your example is fine.

Sometimes you may want to add some default behaviour (just the same as in a `switch()`) which covers the - it didn't match anything else...

```
  if ($_SESSION['session2'] == 'cart') {  
    $code = '1567';
  }
  else if($_SESSION['session2'] == 'online') {  
    $code= 'A90f';
  } 
  else {
    $code = '';
  }
```

But you could alternativelty say

```
  $code = '';
  if ($_SESSION['session2'] == 'cart') {  
    $code = '1567';
  }
  else if($_SESSION['session2'] == 'online') {  
    $code= 'A90f';
  }
```

Comment: You may add example with `switch-case` - it may be useful if he will get one more `if`...

Answer (score 0):

The OP's question concerns the basics of PHP, a worthwhile subject for review whatever one's expertise may be. While a [switch](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) statement may prove useful for avoiding messy looking long if-statements, the OP's code contains a switch statement with only one case that contains itself an if control structure.  So, while the syntax is correct, the switch statement appears superfluous since the if control structure could just as easily execute without being embedded in a switch statement.

As far as the usage concerning **else**, that provides for default code to execute in the case of one or more if-statements evaluating as false. Also, note that the **else if** code only evaluates when the preceding **if** condition returns false.  To illustrate:

```
<?php
  $a = 3;
  $b = 5;

  if ($a == $b) {
         echo '$a and $b are equivalent';
  }
  else
  if ($a > $b) {
        echo '$a is greater than $b';
  }
  else
  {
        echo 'The rain in Spain stays mainly in the plain';
  }
?>
```

See [live code](https://3v4l.org/SoJcf) and read more [here](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php)

You could optionally recode the preceding example using a switch statement as follows:

```
<?php
   $a = 3;
   $b = 5;

   switch($a) {
   case ($b):
         echo '$a and $b are equivalent';
         break;
   case ($a > $b):
        echo '$a is greater than $b';
        break;
   default:
        echo 'The rain in Spain stays mainly in the plain';
        break;
   }
  ?>
```

See [live code](https://3v4l.org/aoHPZ)

With respect to the switch statement the Manual notes:

> In many occasions, you may want to compare the same variable (or
>   expression) with many different values, and execute a different piece
>   of code depending on which value it equals to. This is exactly what
>   the switch statement is for.

Answer (score -1):

@Nigel's answer is fine. I'd just add that I'll rather use `elseif` instead of `else if` for PSR-2 compliance: https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/

The behaviour between `else if` and `elseif` is just the same.